# Get data with from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have these SQL Tables

```
gouvernorat
id  |nom
1   TUNIS
2   ARIANA
3   BEN AROUS
4   MANOUBA
5   NABEUL

delegation
id|id_gouvernorat| nom
1   1              EL MENZAH
2   1              EL HRAIRIA
3   1              EL KABBARIA
22  2              RAOUADE
23  2              SIDI THABET
```

id_gouvernorat is a foreign key of gouvernorat

```
tarifs_zone
zone_a|zone_b|prix
1      2      10
1      3      15
1      4      17
1      5      0
2      3      1
2      4      5
```

zone_a and zone_b are foreign key of delegation

I want to retrieve
The gouvernorat.nom,delegation.nom of zone_a, The gouvernorat.nom,delegation.nom of zone_b and the price without duplcates (A,B without B,A)

```
public function Get_zones($start, $length, $order, $dir,$search,$gouvernorat){
$sql='
SELECT (

SELECT delegation.id_gouvernorat 
FROM delegation 
WHERE tarifs_zones.zone_b=delegation.id) 
AS zoneB, 

gouvernorat.nom AS gouvernoratA, 
gouvernorat.id AS zoneA, 
delegation.nom AS delegationA, 
tarifs_zones.prix AS prix,

(SELECT gouvernorat.nom 
from gouvernorat 
WHERE zoneB=gouvernorat.id) 
AS gouvernoratB,

(SELECT delegation.nom 
FROM delegation 
WHERE tarifs_zones.zone_b=delegation.id) 
AS delegationB

FROM tarifs_zones 

JOIN delegation ON delegation.id = tarifs_zones.zone_a 
JOIN gouvernorat ON delegation.id_gouvernorat = gouvernorat.id 

HAVING (gouvernoratA= \''.$gouvernorat.'\' OR gouvernoratB= \''.$gouvernorat.'\' OR \'Tous les gouvernorats\'=\''.$gouvernorat.'\') 
AND (delegationA LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\' OR gouvernoratA LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\' OR delegationB 

LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\' OR gouvernoratB LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\' OR prix LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\') 

ORDER BY '.$order.' '.$dir.' 
LIMIT '. $start.', '.$length.';
';

return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

This is my function but I feel it's too complex and I can't figure out a way to update the price of all zones depending on two gouvernorat.nom

Comment: Forget about the php for now. Instead, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before asking the next question.

Comment: As far as duplicates, I would get rid of duplicates in the tarifs_zone table separately from this. Then you don't need this query to address that.

Comment: Return all rows and edit them in php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use subqueries behind `SELECT`. You should not be afraid to use the same table twice in the `JOIN`s. You just need to assign aliases in such cases.

Therefore your query will be something like

```
 SELECT d2.id_gouvernorat AS zoneB, 
        g1.nom AS gouvernoratA, 
        g1.id AS zoneA, 
        d1.nom AS delegationA, 
        tarifs_zones.prix AS prix,
        d2.nom AS gouvernoratB,
        d2.nom AS delegationB
 FROM tarifs_zones 
 LEFT JOIN delegation d1 ON d1.id = tarifs_zones.zone_a     // delegation with alias d1 for zone_a
 LEFT JOIN delegation d2 ON d2.id = tarifs_zones.zone_b     // delegation with alias d2 for zone_b
 LEFT JOIN gouvernorat g1 ON d1.id_gouvernorat = g1.id 
 LEFT JOIN gouvernorat g2 ON d2.id_gouvernorat = d2.id 
 HAVING (gouvernoratA= \''.$gouvernorat.'\' OR gouvernoratB= \''.$gouvernorat.'\' OR \'Tous les gouvernorats\'=\''.$gouvernorat.'\') 
      AND (delegationA LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\' OR gouvernoratA LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\' OR delegationB 
      LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\' OR gouvernoratB LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\' OR prix LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\') 
 ORDER BY '.$order.' '.$dir.' 
 LIMIT '. $start.', '.$length.';
```

Comment: It returns 0 rows I think because there can't be any row in tarif_zones like
A A 5 or B B 5, every combination of zone_a and zone_b is unique

Comment: @HaledDo ok, use `LEFT JOIN` then

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great !
Just a small mistype in your answer:
d2.nom AS gouvernoratB -> g2.nom AS gouvernoratB
 LEFT JOIN gouvernorat g2 ON d2.id_gouvernorat = d2.id ->  LEFT JOIN gouvernorat g2 ON d2.id_gouvernorat = g2.id
Thanks again!

Comment: @HaledDo you are welcome, go ahead and edit my answer :)